# how to assign data to fluent ui detailsList

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, powerapps

i am new in PCF Control, i need to create a PCF Control Subgrid using react detailslist . the pcf should use the webAPI to make a webAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords  request and then to assign the result in the Subgrid.

maybe someone has an example for me?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PCF Builder](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Maverick.PCF.Builder/) for XrmToolBox and create the PCF Control with Dataset Template.

This will allow you to replace any sub grid with the PCF control and the data for the sub gird will be passed in the parameters in the context.

You also have access to the [paging](https://dianabirkelbach.wordpress.com/2020/10/05/dataset-pcf-using-fluentui-paging/) on the dataset.